# Function error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Made a script that checks if: `$("#password")` has 9 symbols and if `$("#password") = $("#confirm_password")`.

**The problem is when I try to enable the "submit" button... What is wrong with "function submitButton()"?**

```
$("form span").hide();
$('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "true");

var samePass = false;
var eight = false;

var $password01 = $("#password");
var $password02 = $("#confirm_password")

//Why this function doesn't work?
function submitButton() {
  if (samePass && eight){
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  };
};

//Checks if the pass has 8 symbles
function passwordEvent() {
  if ($password01.val().length > 8) { 
    eight = true;
    $password01.next().hide().submitButton();

  } else {
    $password01.next().show();
  };
};

//Checks if the two passwards are the same
function passwordCheck() {
  if($password02.val() !== $password01.val()) {
    $password02.next().show();
  } else {
    samePass = true;
    $password02.next().hide().submitButton();

  };
};



$password01.focus(passwordEvent).keyup(passwordEvent).focus(passwordCheck).keyup(passwordCheck);
$password02.focus(passwordCheck).keyup(passwordCheck);
```

```js
$("form span").hide();
$('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", "true");

var samePass = false;
var eight = false;

var $password01 = $("#password");
var $password02 = $("#confirm_password")

//Why this function doesn't work?
function submitButton() {
  if (samePass && eight){
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  };
};

//Checks if the pass has 8 symbles
function passwordEvent() {
  if ($password01.val().length > 8) { 
    eight = true;
    $password01.next().hide().submitButton();

  } else {
    $password01.next().show();
  };
};

//Checks if the two passwards are the same
function passwordCheck() {
  if($password02.val() !== $password01.val()) {
    $password02.next().show();
  } else {
    samePass = true;
    $password02.next().hide().submitButton();

  };
};



$password01.focus(passwordEvent).keyup(passwordEvent).focus(passwordCheck).keyup(passwordCheck);
$password02.focus(passwordCheck).keyup(passwordCheck);
```

```css
body {
  background: #384047;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px
}

form {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 4em 4em 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #222;
  
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight:600;
  color: #333;
  
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none
}

input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="password"]:focus {
  background: #fff
}

span {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #2F558E;
  color: #fff;
  
  width: 160px;
  display: block; /* Needed for the width to work */
  
  text-align: center; /* For the inner text */
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 105%;
  top: 25px;
}

span:after {
  content: " ";
  
  position: absolute;
/*  pointer-events: none;*/
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
/*
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
*/
  
  border: solid transparent;
/*  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);*/
  border-right-color: #2F558E;
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.enableSub {
  background: #0099FF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #005C99;
}

.disableSub {
  background: #AEAEAE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sign Up Form</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

 <form action="#" method="post">
  <p>
   <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
  </p>
  <p>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
   <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
   <span>Enter a password longer than 8 characters</span>
  </p>
  <p>
   <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
   <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password">
   <span>Please confirm your password</span>
  </p>
  <p>
   <input type="submit" class="disableSub" value="SUBMIT">
  </p>
 </form>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem? What error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: `submitButton` isn't defined in jquery.  It's your custom function.  Put the submitButton call on a separate line

Comment: "samePass && eight" doesn't work.....

Comment: You can't just tack on `.submitButton()` to anything, i.e., you can't do this: `$password01.next().hide().submitButton();`

Comment: changed but it doesn't enables the button =(

Answer (score 3):

```
$password01.next().hide().submitButton();
```

et al. won't work. You instead need to do;

```
$password01.next().hide();
submitButton();
```

You've declared `submitButton` as a function, not a method on a jQuery object, hence you need to call it as such.

---

The "`undefined` is not a function" error appears cryptic at first, but becomes clear once understood.

Since the jQuery object returned from `hide()` doesn't have a `submitButton` property (or method), `hide().submitButton` returns `undefined`. You're then trying to call that as a function (with the `()`), hence JavaScript is telling  you that `undefined` is not a function.

---

As well as the above, your logic is also flawed. Namely `samePass` is being set to true the second you click into the `password1` field (since, on focus, when they're both blank, `$password02.val() === $password01.val()`). That means that as soon as `password` is > 8 chars, both conditions will match, and your submit will be enabled.

To fix this, you should probably be setting `samePass` and `eight` to false when they *don't* match their criteria, and calling `submitButton()` in all cases to update the state

```
//Why this function doesn't work?
    function submitButton() {
        if (samePass && eight) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', "true");
        }
    };

//Checks if the pass has 8 symbles
function passwordEvent() {
    if ($password01.val().length > 8) {
        eight = true;
        $password01.next().hide();
        submitButton();
    } else {
        eight = false;
        $password01.next().show();
        submitButton();
    };
};

//Checks if the two passwards are the same
function passwordCheck() {
    if ($password02.val() !== $password01.val()) {
        samePass = false;
        $password02.next().show();
        submitButton();
    } else {
        samePass = true;
        $password02.next().hide();
        submitButton();
    };
};
```

... which then works; http://jsfiddle.net/9qqnqLxm/

Comment: changed but it doesn't enables the button =(

Comment: Your logic seems all screwed. Why are you hiding $password2 once $password1 gets longer than 8 characters? Can you post your HTML?

Comment: I am hiding the NEXT element with "next()" =)

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin: In which case, post your HTML. I'm not clairvoyant, and it's really hard to follow what you're doing.

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin: See my update. FYI, I've restored the `submitButton()`'s in the question to as they were when you first posted the question. Don't turn your question into [a chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).